# How to deal with the high dimensionality when using EM algorithm to solve Gaussian mixture models?

Tags: python, clustering, scikit-learn, expectation-maximization, high-dimensional

When I use the EM algorithm to solve a Gaussian mixture model, we may encounter the computation of Gaussian densities in the E step. Specifically, we should have the posterior probability as
$$
\pi_{ik} = \pi_k f_{\mu_k, \Sigma_K}(X_i) \Big/ \sum\limits_{j=1}^K \pi_k f_{\mu_k, \Sigma_K}(X_i),
$$
where $f$ denotes the pdf of Gaussian distribution. However, if the dimension of the feature data is quite high, the density at $X_i$ will be difficult to distinguish. And the posterior probability will be dominated by the proportion $\pi_k$. This leads to the EM algorithm implemented by myself hard to be done.

But when I execute the *GaussianMixture* function in the scikit-learn Python package, it seems that this is not a problem. I have no idea on the reason and this is my implement of a *mean-focused* EM (specifying the conditional covariances as identity matrices) algorithm below. It can provide good result for low-dimensional feature data but fails for high dimension such as $p=512$.

```py
pi_k_est = np.bincount(labels_est) / len(labels_est)     
    # initialized by K-means                                
pi_ik_est = np.zeros([len(label), K])
for t in range(T):
    # E step
    for i in range(len(label)):
        for k in range(K):
            pi_ik_est[i,k] = pi_k_est[k] * Gpdf(feature[i,:], mu_est[k,:])        
        pi_ik_est[i,:] /= sum(pi_ik_est[i,:])              
    
    # M step
    for k in range(K):
        pi_k_est[k] = sum(pi_ik_est[:,k]) / len(label)
    for k in range(K):
        up = np.zeros(p); down = 0
        for i in range(len(label)):
            up += feature[i] * pi_ik_est[i,k]
            down += pi_ik_est[i,k]
        mu_est[k,:] = up / down
```